# Georeferencing in ArcGIS - Zero-Order (Shift)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing

Zero-Order (shift) transformation is meant for rasters that only require shift, which as I understand it means moving or translating the image. Two questions:

1. Does it mean that two or more control points always yield residuals? How does this transformation handle two or more control points?
2. When I do use more than two points it results in an extremely enlarged raster (each pixel kilometers across) which looks like a bug but I assume could be the result of how the transformation works. Any way to explain this?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer, since ESRI code is not exposed as far as I know, thus the algorithm can't be analysed. However, there is a fundemental flaw in your question, that is for shift you should use only 1 GCP: "A zero-order polynomial is used to shift your data. This is commonly used when your data is already georeferenced, but a small shift will better line up your data. Only one link is required to perform a zero-order polynomial shift. It may be a good idea to create a few links, then choose the one that looks the most accurate." [ESRI help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t000000mn000000).That is, using two or more, anchor points to shift a raster is a wrong use of the georefrencing tool.

In another manner, ESRI using the least squares fitting to predict each (x,y) source location to its (x,y) map location. As far as I understand it, when you use a zero-order (shift) fitting, there is actually no fitting, but the raster is shifted using a constant, that is that there is no regrresion and no residuals. Yet, using more than one GCP, against the concept of this specifity of the tool, might "confuse" the program, resulting in residuals and applying a strech to the raster as well.

Wite no source code available I can only suggest that the answers for your questions id:

1. Yes, there will always be residuals; and it can't handle two or more control points well.
2. It might be a "strech" effect, caused by "pulling" your raster in different directions.